# rabbitmq error at startup

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, amqp

This is my setup.

OS: 2.6.35-28-generic-pae #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 20:43:15 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux 
Erlant OTP : R14B03 
RabbitMQ : rabbitmq-server-2.4.1 (built from source using R14B03, used "make USE_SPECS=false" to fix a issue that was poppoing while build.

build goes fine.

when I start server
./rabbitmq-server start, I get following error.

ERROR: generation of boot script file 
/export/workdir/data/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@MyHostname-plugins-expand/rabbit.script failed:
{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{erl_prim_loader,error}},
         [{xref_utils,find_beam,1},
          {xref_base,'-make_libs/5-fun-0-',2},
          {lists,foldl,3},
          {xref_base,make_libs,5},
          {xref_base,do_set_up,1},
          {xref_base,do_set_up,2},
          {xref_base,q,3},
          {xref,handle_call,3}]}}

Any clues, I prefer to use latest version of rabbit and build it myself rather then going to older versions.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is a traceback. If you read and Erlang tutorial, that will explain how to read it.

That sounds to me like a typographical error in a config file. Go over any config file entries that you made, particularly related to plugins.

If you didn't set up any plugins at all, then I suggest downloading the collection of plugins used to make rabbitmq-management work, and configure that. These days it is unusual to have a RabbitMQ install with no plugins at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed that you are on Ubuntu. I recently built RabbitMQ 2.4.1 on Ubuntu and was unable to get a successful build with Erlang 14B03 (which I also built). So I built Erlang 14B02 and used that to build RabbitMQ with no issues at all. Then, I replaced the Erlang with 14B03 to run RabbitMQ and again, no issues.

I didn't use the Ubuntu directory layout or shell scripts, just hacked the standard RabbitMQ scripts to run Rabbit from the directory in which I installed it.

You need to define some environment variables before doing `make install`
export TARGET_DIR=/opt/rabbitmq
export SBIN_DIR=/opt/rabbitmq/sbin
export MAN_DIR=/opt/rabbitmq/man

Answer (score 0):

I got this error running in OS X.   The issue for me was that my user account did not have permissions to create the the boot script file.  Starting the rabbit server using sudo solved the problem.